# How to override .cpt (Custom Form Controller) templates in diazo?

Tags: plone, diazo

I want to override Plone's contact-info template in a diazo based product. The contact-info is a .cpt (Custom Form Controller Template).

The [recommended](http://developer.plone.org/templates_css_and_javascripts/template_basics.html#overriding-templates) approach to customize .pt files for Plone 4 is to use [z3c.jbot](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.jbot).

Is it possible in diazo to override .cpt files in a similar way like .pt files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your "diazo-based product" is a design for Plone. The answer is that yes, that product can override the cpt, and the best way to do that is to use z3c.jbot.

Diazo in itself has no possibility to override templates. It works purely on the HTML that the template renders to. But there isn't any problems in including both a Diazo-based design and other features such as template overrides in the same product.

Comment: If you need a package skeleton, use zopeskel and zopeskel.diazo. The zopeskel.diazo package combines diazo and z3c.jbot.

Comment: Thank you. After reinstalling the Product both .cpt and .pt are overriden.